# Is ARP contained into MAC sublayer (OSI Model)?

Tags: networking, network-protocols

Well, I've read that the Data Link layer is further divided into LLC and MAC sublayers.

However, the description of the MAC functions seems just like what the ARP does, which left me a bit confused.

Is the MAC sublayer a purely conceptual thing while the ARP is a concrete implementation?

Thanks in advance for your patience :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! I think this question might fit better on the network engineering or superuser stackexchange since StackeOverflow usually involves questions with some aspect of programming. Did you check if theres a similar question over there?

Comment: @jvda Hey there, thanks for the warm welcome 8) Hitherto I've limited my search to books and StackOverflow. Will give a look into superuser stackexchange but I'm not very hopeful about it, as the base is bigger here. Nevertheless, it seems quite a simple question, so I was expecting someone would pass by and drop an answer quickly...

Comment: ARP isn't in the OSI model at all. It is in the TCP/IP model. The OSI model (a) applies to the OSI protocol stack and therefore (b) is defunct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point of the MAC sublayer of the data-link layer is to abstract hardware details to the LLC, which is often implemented in software. Therefore the way, how an ARP request is implemented actually depends on the physical medium below - but I'd say ARP in general is just a service part of the MAC layer whose implementation depends on various linklayer protocols (e.g. Ethernet vs Wifi).

Comment: So, the whole MAC sublayer might be implemented straight on hardware, the hard/soft line is still blurry at data link layer... Thanks for taking your time!